# How close are we to measure Planck time

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time

I know that Plack time is considered a fundamental time unit by some of the physicists. To test this we need to try to falsify it. I want to learn what the smallest time interval we can measure is.

Comment: You might have to define what, specifically, you mean by "measure" here. Based on decay products, we can infer the lifetime of particles that only exist for $10^{-25}$ seconds  or shorter, but some might not call that a direct measurement of time.

Comment: @probably_someone my idea was to measure the time itself. Years ago we could make precise mechanical watches. Now we can produce atomic clocks that can measure the time based on decay products. Are there any methods to make a more accurate clock that can reach the Planck time interval?

Comment: The accuracy of an atomic clock doesn't really have all that much to do with the shortest time interval we can measure, though, since we don't always use atomic clocks to measure time intervals. For example, the current record-holder for "shortest time interval directly measured" used the spatial (and temporal) profile of an extremely short laser pulse to measure a 20-attosecond delay between radiation absorption and emission. But such a measurement does not constitute a clock, as it's a one-time measurement and not a continuous tracker of elapsed time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Planck time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time) is about $10^{-44}$ s. The most accurate and expensive clocks can currently resolve in the order between $10^{-16}$ to $10^{-18}$ s according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_clock). So we are still many years and dollars away from the Plank time.